# Trouble importing variables from one file to another

Tags: python

Apologies if I am duplicating a questions, but I have tried the numerous possible solutions and it still doesn't work.

I saved log-in information in a file called `Login.py` which contains:

```
username = 'username'
password = 'password'
```

I want to import this into another script file.  I tried:

```
from Login import username, password
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-d732c46e191a> in <module>
----> 2 from Login import username, password

ImportError: cannot import name 'username' from 'Login'
```

I tried:

```
from Login import *

Login.username
Login.password
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-31add6b3211f> in <module>
----> 1 Login.username
      2 Login.password

AttributeError: module 'Login' has no attribute 'username'
```

I tried:

```
from Login import *

username
password
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-1731614b5154> in <module>
----> 1 username
      2 password

NameError: name 'username' is not defined
```

Finally, I tried:

```
import Login
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-31add6b3211f> in <module>
----> 1 Login.username
      2 Login.password

AttributeError: module 'Login' has no attribute 'username'
```

Both files are in the same working directory.  What am I missing and haven't tried yet?

Comment: Add information about python version. Check what file you loaded by `print(Login.__file__)`

Comment: Make sure that there isn't another module named `Login` in the directories in `sys.path`!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Login.py 
username = 'username'
password = 'password'

# Other file.py
import Login
print(Login.username)
print(Login.password)
```

This should work or you have a working environment issue. If this is the case, look into adding the specific path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/path/to/other/script/folder')
```

Also, make sure folder also contains an **init**.py, this allows it to be included as a package.

Comment: I copied and pasted that code in with the directory to the other script folder (which I find odd since both files are in the same folder), and it disabled my keyboard.  I had to reboot.  Now, the keyboard is restored, but shift+enter doesn't execute the cell. Using Jupyter notebook.

Comment: is your Login file a jupyter notebook as well ?! you might want to look into this: https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/examples/Notebook/Importing%20Notebooks.html

Comment: Yes, Jupyter notebook/lab is my primary python platform.

Comment: So I added `import sys` and `sys.path.append('.../path/...')`, then added `__init__.py`  so that now when I run `import Login` then `Login`, it prints out `<module 'Login' from 'C:\\Users\\...\\Login.py'>`.  When I execute `print(Login.__file__)`, it prints out `C:\Users\...\Login.py`, so it recognizes it. Yet when I do `Login.username` or `username` or `print(Login.username)`, it still gives me `AttributeError: module 'Login' has no attribute 'username'`

Answer (score 0):

Login.py

```
class login:
def username():
    return 'username'
def password():
    return 'password'
```

Now try this:

```
>>> from Login import login
>>> print(login.username())
'username'
>>> print(login.password())
'password'
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it working!

Since `Login.py` is a really small file, I decided to delete all traces of the file and start over.  I made sure to have `__init__.py` in my working directory, and I included `import sys` and `sys.path.append('\working\directory\')` in my main script.  I then started a new text file called `TLogin.txt` with identical code as the file I deleted.  Then I changed the extension from `txt` to `py`.  That finally worked.

Thanks for all the help.